# Is it possible to create a ramdisk of more than 4 gb in a 32bit system?

Tags: 10.04

I'm planning on building my desktop computer to have a ramdisk. At the moment my pc has 4 gb ram, and I was thinking if it is possible to go beyond 4 gb and use the extra ram as a ramdisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It looks like you can: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/  You would have to find the device names of the extra RAM and then follow that tutorial or one that is similar.

Comment: The default ramdisk size is 64M so you would need to use the ramdisk_size= kernel argument to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off letting the kernel manage the ram for you.  It will allocate the ram to applications that need it ( up to 3GB per process ), and use any free ram to cache files automatically.